# Is it possible to enable proxy_protocol only for one host on NGINX?

Tags: nginx

Say I have two hosts, `a.example.com` and `b.example.com` and only wish to enable `proxy_protocol` on `a.example.com` which is behind a load balancer (`b.example.com` is used for direct healthchecks). Tried the following setup but getting an error.

**a.example.com**

```
server {
    listen 80 proxy_protocol;
    listen 443 proxy_protocol ssl;

    server_name a.example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8443;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_protocol_addr;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/a.example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/a.example.com/privkey.pem;
}
```

**b.example.com**

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name b.example.com;

    location /healthcheck {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8443;
        access_log off;
    }
}
```

**Error**

```
2019/08/06 17:40:50 [error] 10488#10488: *12 broken header: "GET /healthcheck HTTP/1.1
Host: b.example.com
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.142 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9

" while reading PROXY protocol, client: 1.2.3.4, server: 0.0.0.0:80
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `proxy_protocol` is enabled for a listener on a given port, it applies to all `server` blocks that `listen` on that same port, whether they were specified or not. There is no way to override this for any particular `server` block. You will need to ensure that all traffic to that port either uses the PROXY protocol, or does not use it.